# How to use ContentWrapperAttribute in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I've been trying to create a small proof of concept that use the `ContentWrapperAttribute` but I can't get either the XamlXmlReader or XamlObjectWriter to respect it, it just throws an exception saying it can't add "String" to the collection.

I've defined a small object model like this:

```
[ContentProperty("MyItems")]
public class RootClass
{
    public RootClass()
    {
        this.MyItems = new MyItemCollection();
    }

    public MyItemCollection MyItems { get; set; }
}

[ContentWrapper(typeof(MyItemText))]
public class MyItemCollection : List<MyItem>
{
}

[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class MyItemText : MyItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem
{
}
```

And I'm trying to use this code to load the Xaml:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<RootClass xmlns=""clr-namespace:XamlTest;assembly=XamlTest"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
    <MyItem />
    <x:String>test</x:String>
</RootClass>
";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

XamlReader xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(reader, new XamlSchemaContext());

XamlObjectWriter xow = new XamlObjectWriter(xamlReader.SchemaContext);
while (xamlReader.Read())
    xow.WriteNode(xamlReader);
xow.Close();

RootClass result = (RootClass)xow.Result;
```

I get a `System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException` stating that: "Add value to collection of type 'XamlTest.MyItemCollection' threw an exception." and an inner `System.ArgumentException` exception claiming:
"The value "test" is not of type "XamlTest.MyItem" and cannot be used in this generic collection.".

Is the `ContentWrapperAttribute` supposed to picked up by the XamlXmlReader or the XamlObjectWriter, or am I misunderstanding what this attribute does? If not, has anyone actually gotten this to work?